# No matching function in rectangle class

Tags: c++

So im making a program the take the width and height, using 3 classes. The first to initialize the 2 variable, the second to print the value from the third class.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class polygon
{
    protected:
        int width, height;
    public:
        polygon(int a, int b)
        {
            width=a;
            height=b;
        }
}; 
class output
{
    public:
        void print(int a)
        {
            cout<<a<<"\n";
        }
};
class rectangle: public 
polygon,public output
{
    public:
        rectangle (int a, int b)
        {
            width=a;
            height=b;
        }
        int area()
        {
            return width*height;
        }

};
int main()
{
    rectangle rect(5,6);
    rect.print(rect.area());
    return 0;
}
```

The error message"
no matching function for call to polygon:: polygon()"

Comment: Both [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/501250) and [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/501250) are bad ideas. I'd suggest not using either.

Comment: Why it's a bad idea?

Comment: Did you click either of the links in my comment? The linked questions document the reasons quite well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you didn't specify a `polygon` constructor to call in the `rectangle(int, int)` constructor, it implicitly calls the default constructor from `polygon` -- but there is no such constructor, so you get this error.  You need to explicitly chain to the appropriate `polygon` constructor, and then you can also remove the assignments:

```
rectangle(int a, int b) : polygon(a, b) { }
```

Note that since this constructor simply passes its arguments straight through to the `polygon` constructor, you can also opt to just bring all of the constructors from `polygon` into `rectangle` by *replacing* your `rectangle` constructor with:

```
using polygon::polygon;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class rectangle: public polygon, public output {
public:
    rectangle (int a, int b) { // Nowhere polygon's constructor declared which
            width = a;         // requires nothing to get constructed
            height = b;
    }
    int area() {
            return width * height;
    }
};
```

In the class `polygon`, define the constructor explicitly:

```
polygon() {}
```

To remove the conflict.